# Getting NameError: variable not defined when it is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods

I'm trying to create a simple survey by creating a class and creating an instance of it in another file. My problem is that I am getting an error that says my 'question' variable is not defined when I clearly defined it in the start of my program. Here's the error:

```
line 11, in show_question print(question) /
  NameError: name 'question' is not defined
```

Here is the class I am instancing:

```
class AnonymousSurvey():
    """Collect anonymous answers to a survey question."""

    def __init__(self, question):
        """Store a question, and prepare to store responses."""
        self.question = question
        self.responses = []

    def show_question(self):
        """Show the survey question."""
        print(question)
```

And here's the code I am working with:

```
from survey import AnonymousSurvey

#   Define a question, and make a survey.
question = "What language did you first learn to speak?"
my_survey = AnonymousSurvey(question)

#   Show the question, and store responses to the question.
my_survey.show_question()
print("Enter 'q' at any time to quit.\n")
while True:
    response = input("Language: ")
    if response == 'q':
        break
    my_survey.store_response(response)
```

I am running python v.3.5.2

If there are other details you think will be needed, I'll be happy to provide them.

Comment: should reference `question` via `self`, i.e use `print(self.question)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that function. `question` isn't defined.  You do, however, have `self.question`. `question` is local to the `__init__` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def show_question(self):
    """Show the survey question."""
    print(self.question)
```

In Python, you have to access class instance attribute with `self`.

Comment: that's an instance attribute. not a class "field".

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard yeah thanks. I couldn't think of that when I wrote this